# Associative array pipe to Column command

Tags: bash

Im looking for a way to print out an Associative array with the `column` command and I fill like there is probably a way to do this, but I havent had much luck.

```
declare -A list
list=(
  [a]="x is in this one"
  [b]="y is here"
  [areallylongone]="z down here"
)
```

I'd like the outcome to be a simple table. I've used a loop with tabs but in my case the lengths are great enough to offset the second column.

The output should look like

```
a               x is in this one
b               y is here
areallylongone  z down here
```

Comment: What would the desired output look like? What does yours look like? Could you add the code you used?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for something like this?

```
declare -A assoc=(
  [a]="x is in this one"
  [b]="y is here"
  [areallylongone]="z down here"
)

for i in "${!assoc[@]}" ; do
    echo -e "${i}\t=\t${assoc[$i]}"
done | column -s$'\t' -t
```

Output:

```
areallylongone  =  z down here
a               =  x is in this one
b               =  y is here
```

I'm using a tab char to delimit key and value and use the `column -t` to tabulate the output and `-s` to set the input delimiter to the tab char. From `man column`:

> `-t`      Determine the number of columns the input contains and create a table.  Columns are delimited with whitespace, by default, or with the charac‐
>                ters supplied using the -s option.  Useful for pretty-printing displays
>
> `-s`      Specify a set of characters to be used to delimit columns for the -t option.

Comment: I've updated the question, but the value's have spaces, which column is replacing with tabs. Tried a couple of things to do that (Such as quoting the value on the echo). Thanks!

Comment: Check my update. I'm now separating `KEY=VALUE` by tabs an use tab as the delimiter for `column`

Answer (score 1):

One (simple) way to do it is by *pasting together keys column and values column*:

```
paste -d $'\t' <(printf "%s\n" "${!list[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${list[@]}") | column -s $'\t' -t
```

For your input, it yields:

```
areallylongone  z down here
a               x is in this one
b               y is here
```

To handle spaces in (both) keys and values, we used `TAB` (`\t`) as column delimiter, in both `paste` (`-d` option) and `column` (`-s` option) commands.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the desired output from the answer of hek2mgl

```
 declare -A assoc=(
  [a]="x is in this one"
  [b]="y is here"
  [areallylongone]="z down here"
  )
for i in "${!assoc[@]}" ; do
  echo "${i}=${assoc[$i]}"
done | column -s= -t | sort -k 2
```